# LinkedList offers several methods for the same function- Why?

Tags: java, collections, linked-list

I was checking `Java.util.LinkedList` class and  found that Linked List class offers several methods

```
public void addFirst(E e) 

public boolean offerFirst(E e)

public void push(E e)
```

All these 3 methods add an element to the head of the list.
So why does different implementation require for the same function?

Is it because 
push is meant for Stack and

offerFirst – Dequeue

addFirst – LinkedList

or some other fundamentals?

Please share some insight here. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

These are implemented in `LinkedList` due to the contract of `Deque` interface.

And the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) for `Deque` clearly explain the difference:

> void addFirst(E e)
>
> Inserts the specified element at the front of this deque if it is possible to do so immediately without violating capacity restrictions. **When using a capacity-restricted deque, it is generally preferable to use method offerFirst(E).**
>
> boolean offerFirst(E e)
>
> Inserts the specified element at the front of this deque unless it would violate capacity restrictions. When using a capacity-restricted deque, **this method is generally preferable to the addFirst(E) method, which can fail to insert an element only by throwing an exception.**

The `ArrayBlockingQueue` class ([javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html)) is an example of a bounded queue implementation that implements `Deque`.

Answer (score 0):

Spend a look ad the java docs..

```
public void addFirst(E e) 
// Inserts the specified element at the beginning of this list.

public boolean offerFirst(E e)
// Inserts the specified element at the front of this list.

public void push(E e)
// Pushes an element onto the stack represented by this list.
```

For more infos: [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)

Comment: `public void addFirst(E e)`
Inserts the specified element at the beginning of this list.
Specified by:
addFirst in interface **Deque<E>**
Parameters:
e - the element to add


`public boolean offerFirst(E e)`
Inserts the specified element at the front of this list.
Specified by:
offerFirst in interface **Deque<E>**
Parameters:
e - the element to insert
Returns:
true (as specified by Deque.offerFirst(E))


It seems same to me!
There isn't any information about exception thrown.